# Sinon TypeError: '[object ProgressEventConstructor]' in Karma/SauceLabs testing

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner, travis-ci, sinon, saucelabs

I'm migrating a framework Specs to run with Karma/Jasmin/Grunt and Travis/SauceLabs

While running the specs I get errors in all Ajax specs for some browsers.

PhantomJS/Opera/Chrome && FF are all green. No errors.

Safari give this same error in all those 13 Specs in Sinon.js:

```
TypeError: '[object ProgressEventConstructor]' is not a constructor 
    (evaluating 'new ProgressEvent("progress", {loaded: 100, total: 100})')
```

In IE I get another text for the same error:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this action
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with updating the version of Sinon.js

Att the moment the new version was not released yet, plus that I concated sinon-IE into it. So if anyone needs [its here](https://gist.github.com/SergioCrisostomo/9872135).

Answer (score 1):

Sinon appears to be checking the following...

```
var supportsProgress = typeof ProgressEvent !== "undefined";
```

I think some of those browsers return an empty object for ProgressEvent instead of undefined which throws off this check.

I've manually changed my code because i don't care about the ProgressEvent (this was easy but isn't very practical for CI purposes). I'm looking into changing the value of supportsProgress in my tests to avoid the issue entirely.

**UPDATE**
This was happening to me because i was using an older version of SinonJS in my tests. It's FakeXMLHttpRequest object was causing the ProgressEvent to be created during the readyState updated process.

I talked to the folks over at SinonJS. They recommended going to version 1.9.0.
This appears to have solved all my problems :)